# Как отправить комментарий через vk api?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

При попытке отправить комментарий выдает ошибку Acces Denied
Доступ есть, комментарии писать можно, авторизация ошибок не выдает

```
import vk_api

def main():
    accs = input("Account list: ")
    group = input("Group id to kill: ")
    post = "ADMIN == CLOWN! !DELETE YOUR CRINGE GROUP"
    accs = open(accs,"r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
    for acc in accs:
        login = acc.split(":")[0]
        password = acc.split(":")[1]
        token = acc.split(":")[2]
        token = token.split("\n")[0]
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password, token, scope='wall, messages')
        vk_session.auth()
        vk = vk_session.get_api()
        resp = vk.wall.get(owner_id = "-" + group)
        resp = resp["items"]
        for postid in resp:
            postid = postid["id"]
            print(postid)
            for x in range(10):
                response = vk.wall.createComment(owner_id = group,post_id = postid, message = post)
    print("Final!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У вас есть доступ в эту группу? Там разрешено писать комментарии под указанными постами или нет? Авторизация прошла успешно?

Comment: Доступ есть, комментарии писать можно, авторизаия ошибок не выдает

Comment: Этот все нужно указывать в теле вопроса